# Http request taking too much time even after using PoolHttpClientConnectionManager

Tags: spring, spring-boot, httprequest, apache-httpclient-5.x

I have a API hosted on Kubernetes and created using spring boot,in which we send request to another API. I want to reduce time for Http calls as it is taking almost 2-3 sec for calls. We introduced `PoolHttpClientConnectionManager` with `MaxConnTotal` and `MaxConnPerRoute` as 100. After introducing we saw that calls are showing random behaviour like sometimes it takes 600ms and sometimes it is taking 2-3 sec and sometimes more than that. We are having hard time in going forward with that randomness. We need to reduce down to best possible values as we are catering to another application which is realtime process.

Comment: Instead of throwing random things in there, first determine **what** is slow. If that is the remote api there is nothing in your application you can do to speed that up.

Comment: Actually our API calls another API multiple times based on data we have and those calls we are going parallelly but in those requests, initial requests are faster like 200ms and later ones are slower like 2200ms, so overall time of application is getting increased.

Comment: Still figure out was is slow in those calls. Is it you or the remote server. If it is you investigate which/what is slow.

Comment: Remote API is fast enough as we see response time 200-300ms for request but as much as I understand it is taking time to rebuild connection and to make connection to gateway

Comment: That is for a single request, you are sending multiple requests in parallel (at least that is what you are stating) which increases the load. Measure the individual parts and figure out what is slow, without measuring it is trying random things without knowing. That being said your question is lacking information on configuration and implementation of what you are actually doing.